# Android animationUtils or AnimatorSet problms

Tags: android, android-studio

https://youtu.be/1c2TYKv50Ic
What is the bonus (HEMEN AL)button animation code included in the video. Could you help

code:

```
int basY =100;
    int sonY = 10;
    CipView cip = new CipView(context);
    AnimatorSet1 = new AnimatorSet();
    ObjectAnimator starScaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cip, View.SCALE_Y, 0.5f);
    starScaleYAnimator.setDuration(350);
    starScaleYAnimator.setStartDelay(300);
    ObjectAnimator starScaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cip, View.SCALE_X, 0.5f);
    starScaleXAnimator.setDuration(350);
    starScaleXAnimator.setStartDelay(300);
    AnimatorSet1.playTogether(starScaleYAnimator, starScaleXAnimator);
    AnimatorSet1.start();
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain to us what you need and what you have tried?

Comment: of course, but it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

```
        int basY =100;
        int sonY = 10;
        CipView cip = new CipView(context);
        AnimatorSet1 = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator starScaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cip, "scaleY", basY, sonY);
        starScaleYAnimator.setDuration(350);
        starScaleYAnimator.setStartDelay(300);
        ObjectAnimator starScaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cip, "scaleX", basY, sonY);
        starScaleXAnimator.setDuration(350);
        starScaleXAnimator.setStartDelay(300);
        AnimatorSet1.playTogether(starScaleYAnimator, starScaleXAnimator);
        AnimatorSet1.start();
```